# SVN FTP Upload with multiple FTP accounts

Tags: svn, upload, ftp, post-commit

We have multiple ftp accounts for each website and recently have set up the folder with all the websites inside of a SVN Repository. What would be the best approach to set it up so it would upload on commit to the respective ftp account based on it's folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to write a script (shell, perl, or whatever) that ftp's files and/or directories from the svn repository to one or more ftp sites. This script could then be run from a [svn hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)

I believe there is a "post-commit" hook which you might be able to take advantage of.